# How to display the visitor country in the drupal statistics

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The statistics (default) module in drupal store and display the IP address of visitors (anonymous or not). Is it possible to display along, the IP address the country ?

I've seen there are different modules to display user country, but them seems to be  only for registered user and not for the report/statistics.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Statistics Advanced Settings](http://drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced) module. It will display IP and its country.

Comment: Have installed it, and there is no country information whatsoever. Does it need an extra module ?